# Точка после привилегий

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, дизайн

> привилегии •
>   знаки

Нет смысла ставить такого вида разделитель при том, что слова написаны в столбик.
There is no sence in such separator as items are written in a column.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Видимо, придётся нам менять `привилегии` на `прив.` чтоб дизайну соответствовать :-D Хотя дело, вероятно, в слишком длинном UTC.

Comment: @alexolut, а мне в 2 строки нравится)

Comment: @alexolut, хотя на мобильнике кто-то помучается :D

Comment: «Универсальное глобальное время» — плохо. Так никто не говорит. Все (программисты) знают про UTC. А кто не знает, пусть посмотрит в вики :)

Comment: @alexolut, блин.. до меня только сейчас дошло, про что [этот вопрос](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5329/178988).

Comment: @VladD надо сделать перевод таким образом, чтобы была ссылка на вики сразу :)

Comment: @alexolut, а почему вообще время - это достижение?

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо, потому что оно и раньше там было. Его может был бы смысл вообще во всех менюшках продублировать. P.S. достижение времени!

Comment: Но раньше оно не было прямо под заголовком?

Comment: @Qwertiy осталось там же, [где и было](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6G1z.jpg).

Comment: @alexolut, теперь - да - справа, а не под))

Answer (score 2):

Эти две надписи должны быть расположены в одну строку. Исправили за счет изменения строки перевода для времени. Со следующей сборкой должно быть доступно.

Comment: Справка - чат - выйти - тоже в одну строку, но точек там нет. Может всё-таки как-то поединообразнее надо?